# Unable to post images on S.O.?

Tags: discussion, bug

[image]

So, I am attempting to add an image to a post and I get an error the image of which, ironically, I have posted along with this post.

**What is causing this error ??**

Link here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW0je.jpg

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186430/205508

Comment: To the person who flagged it as a duplicate ... mate, there is no answer on that post and there is no reason to gimme a -1

Comment: I didn't flag it as a duplicate, but it sure seems to be; the question it is a duplicate of was asked before yours, and details the same problem; lack of an answer doesn't mean it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @Daedalus The only one people who can answer this are the guys from `ServerFault` or the devs of this site themselves :-)

Comment: @LittleChild I don't see how others from another network site would be able to answer that question, when they don't have access to the necessary files.  The devs of this site would be able to, but not otherwise.  This is of course referring to the question that this one seems to be a duplicate of, as the problem demonstrated here, before your edit, is already answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you post a link you must link directly to the *image*. The URL you gave links to the info-page of the image. Try https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkOos.png instead:

[image: actual image]

Comment: No ... No .... I tried to upload the pic straight from my computer first .. then, too, I got the same error

Comment: @Daedalus Isn't loading, for me, too.

Comment: @Johnツ LoL ! Images from older posts do load so this must be a fairly recent problem :)

Comment: Yes, I've already asked [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186430/205508).

Comment: @Johnツ I deleted my comment because the image then loaded for me, I should have actually looked at the image, which is of course likely not the image meant, haha.

Comment: @Johnツ but there is no answer :)

Comment: @LittleChild Waiting for one... :-)

Comment: @Johnツ MAGIC !! Now it loads !! :-D