# Profile Flair Bug

Tags: bug, flair, profile-picture

I am having problem in the Flair of my StackOverflow profile. The picture of any other user or person and reputation and badges are mine. What it can be ? and why ?

The picture in the flair shown shown is never mine or thats not me at all.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181225/jibran-khan/flair

Comment: I don't quite get what you're saying here :/

Comment: @Manishearth The user image in his flair is not any of the images he's actually using. Given that it's an Imgur image though, I would hazard a guess it's connected to this CloudFlare/Imgur issue.

Comment: Exactly @Bart, The picture is never mine.

Comment: @Bart ah, I tried to check out his SO image but my proxy hiccuped on it. I'll tunnel out and see what this cloudflare business is about

Comment: @Bart looks like some images work and others don't. Could be a load balancer issue.

Comment: For the CloudFlare issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186430/upload-image-isnt-working Some users see no images, some see random ones.

Comment: Profile images are also not updating. Showing empty image.

Comment: I dont know how this a duplicate of the question mentioned. The image showing in my flair is not me and i never ever uploaded such image so its messing up the profile flairs. Please see carefully.

Comment: It is the same underlying issue.