# Image not displaying on mouseover at review page

Tags: bug

If you look on the review page on SO you can see the last 6 people who have reviewed. When looking at some of those people I noticed that it sometimes does not display the image for certain persons. Instead of showing the profile image it shows this:

[image]

This only happens on specific users and I could only find 2 persons where the same thing happens. These 2 persons are:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225359/leon-sfs
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2345913/crusader

I know this is kinda hard to reproduce since it almost never occurs but maybe someone can take a look if they see something wrong.

A couple of hours after seeing this the first time I saw the same user in the list and it still did not display the right image so it really is user specific.

Comment: [Same issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186496/profile-flair-bug)